# Buffer overflow in scanf()

Tags: c

I was looking online for solution for this problem with no result. I'm trying to do while loop to read only characters using scanf(). If user type more than 3 characters than it will display error.

However, my code works partially if I type 3 characters and press enter it works without executing loop this is what I want. If I type 4 characters and press enter also works it executes loop and says "too long" same for 5 char + enter also what I want.

However, if I type 7 characters and enter it executes loop and exits program right away. Any advice?

Ps. I apologize for any grammar error but English is  my second language.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
char alo;
char alo1; 
char alo2; 
char alo3;

printf("enter 3 characters: ");
scanf(" %c %c %c%c", &alo, &alo1, &alo2, &alo3); 

while(alo3!='\r' && alo3!='\n'){
    printf("too long \n");
    printf("enter ");       
    scanf(" %c %c %c%c", &alo, &alo1, &alo2, &alo3); 
}   
return 0;
}
```

Comment: FYI, when you press enter. You entered another character.

Comment: When 7 characters are entered, the first `scanf` reads 4 characters, and the second `scanf` reads the other 3 characters and the newline. To avoid the problem, you should read a line with `fgets` and then parse the line with `sscanf`.

Comment: With the 7-character (plus newline) input, you get told 'too long' and 'enter' but it doesn't wait for you to type anything.  And maybe you don't notice the output because your terminal window vanishes as the program exits.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I am able to see "to long" and "enter" before window vanishes, but how to prompt for an input with 7 characters and not exits the program?

Comment: Use a buffer that's long (4096 bytes?) and use `fgets()` to read a line. Then use `sscanf()` to analyze the input. One advantage is you can include what they typed in the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Using `scanf()` only

Using just `scanf()` to achieve this requires a certain amount of jiggery-pokery.  It isn't the best way to code it, but…

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char alo0;
    char alo1;
    char alo2;
    char alo3;

    printf("enter 3 characters: ");

    while (scanf(" %c %c %c%c", &alo0, &alo1, &alo2, &alo3) == 4 &&
           alo3 != '\r' && alo3 != '\n')
    {
        char buffer[4096];
        if (scanf("%4095[^\n]", buffer) == EOF)
            break;
        printf("too long\n");
        printf("enter 3 characters: ");
    }

    printf("Got [%c][%c][%c]\n", alo0, alo1, alo2);
    return 0;
}
```

The `while()` condition uses `scanf()` to read four characters, skipping white space before the first three.  Note that it is OK to put newlines in between characters; `scanf()` doesn't care.  If you want line-based input, `scanf()` is simply the wrong tool for the job!  However, assuming that 4 characters are read and the fourth is neither carriage return nor newline, then the code uses:

```
        char buffer[4096];
        if (scanf("%4095[^\n]", buffer) == EOF)
            break;
```

to read any characters up to, but not including, a newline.  It doesn't mind if there are no such characters so `scanf()` returns 0.  The code then prompts you to enter the correct data and goes around to the main `scanf()`.  This skips the newline that was left behind and then looks for three characters again.

When the `while` loop exits, it could be because it got three characters and a newline, or because it got fewer characters and EOF, or because the clean-up `scanf()` detected EOF.  The code doesn't attempt to distinguish between these (but it should) and simply prints out three values.  Fixing that is not dreadfully hard; simply assign the return from each `scanf()` to a variable and then test that after the loop:

```
int rc;
while ((rc = scanf(…)) == 4 && …)
{
    …
    if ((rc = scanf(…)) == EOF) 
        break;
    …
}

if (rc == 4)
    printf(…);
else
    printf("Didn't get 3 characters as requested\n");
```

#### Using `fgets()` for line input

Personally, I think it is easier/better to use `fgets()` and `sscanf()` like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char alo0;
    char alo1;
    char alo2;
    char alo3;
    char buffer[4096];
    int rc = 0;

    printf("enter 3 characters: ");

    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != 0 &&
           (rc = sscanf(buffer, " %c %c %c%c", &alo0, &alo1, &alo2, &alo3)) == 4 &&
           alo3 != '\r' && alo3 != '\n')
    {
        printf("too long\n");
        printf("enter 3 characters: ");
        // In case you get 4 characters but the 4th was not a newline
        // and then you get EOF
        rc = 0;
    }

    if (rc == 4)
        printf("Got [%c][%c][%c]\n", alo0, alo1, alo2);
    else
        printf("Didn't get 3 characters as requested\n");
    return 0;
}
```

This could report the string that was too long, or otherwise incorrect.

Comment: Thank you. That make sens. But, what about if i can't use arrays and strings, Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Well, I suppose you could drop `buffer` and use `if (scanf("%*4095[^\n]") == EOF)` where the `*` suppresses assignment.  But if that won't do for you, you'll have to invent a solution for yourself — it isn't worth spending the time thinking about it as the constraint being proposed is not realistic.  You can scrutinize the POSIX specification for [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html) to come up with any more ideas — and the best of luck.